# How to disable command + q for Terminal on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to disable the cmd + q hotkey for Terminal on OSX? and if so then how?

Answer (score 16):

You have two options:

1. Assign a different shortcut that's not as prone to be hit accidentally.
2. delete the existing shortcut

Option 1 can be accomplished in *System Preferences* » *Keyboard* » *Keyboard Shortcuts* » *Application Shortcuts*. As an example how option 1 looks like:
[image]

[image]

---

Option 2 (removing the keyboard shortcut) requires the `Terminal`. Simply enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit Terminal" nil
```

*Thanks @Arjan!*

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit Terminal" nil` removes the shortcut altogether.

Comment: @Arjan Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I found it here: http://www.oreillynet.com//cs/user/view/cs_msg/46459 (there's a link to the main article, but it's the user comment that I learned this from.)

Comment: For Option 1: you have to enter the menu name as you see it in your application. In my case, I want to deactivate Command-Q for a German Firefox. The entry is therefore `Firefox beenden`, which I have linked to Command-Shift-R.

Comment: @Arjan 10 years later this is still working :) And this is awesome. I have just used this with UnityHub because I kept forgetting that there was an active download and quit it, and ruined my download. Just typed "`defaults write com.unity3d.unityhub NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit UnityHub" nil`" and completely disabled command-q.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to disable command-q because you're closing command-line programs accidentally, you can get Terminal to warn you before closing. Go into the Settings section of the Terminal -> Preferences... menu item and select the set up you use ("Basic" is the default). Then, under the shell tab is "Prompt before closing" - if you set this to "always", you'll be asked for confirmation if you hit command-q by accident. Alternatively, you can set a list of programs that won't interrupt you (mostly remote shells by default), while others will still cause a prompt.

Comment: Nice! Odd that things like `ssh` are listed as a default in "Prompt before closing".

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend overwriting a keyboard shortcut like the show/hide the panel (or anything that's not as "painfull" as terminating applications). Then nothing serious happens when you accidentally click the command+Q combo.

How?

1. go the apple icon
2. then "System preferences..."
3. then "Keyboard"
4. then "shortcuts"
5. and then "Launchpad & Dock"
6. Change the shortcut for "Turn Dock hiding On/Off" to command+Q

This screenshot shows what to do:

[image]

Comment: This answer is under-rated!

Comment: @akirekadu - it's not really. It introduces potential conflict with all other apps that use Cmd/Q.

Comment: Fair! while in my question I mentioned the Terminal app, in my mind I wanted CMD-Q disabled across the board.