# Is it possible to remove a built-in shortcut from an application in Mac OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts

Long story short, I want to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> for "Save As" in TexMaker, my favorite OS X LaTeX editor.

But <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, the standard "Save as" shortcut, is already taken by some worthless formatting shortcut.

Oddly enough TexMaker doesn't call the menu item "Save As..." either, but just "Save As." So I can go into `System Prefs -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts`, select TexMaker, type "Save As," and set <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> as the shortcut, and it shows up in the application's menu, but there's this other formatting shortcut that it recognizes as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> too.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to remove its built-in <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and replace it with the one I want. OS X 10.6.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/222440/how-to-disable-command-q-for-terminal-on-osx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Set the worthless formatting menu item's shortcut to something difficult to press instead, thereby freeing <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.
- Run the following in Terminal to *remove* the shortcut from the menu item labeled *Worthless Formatting Shortcut*:

  ```
  defaults write com.vendor.yourapp NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Worthless Formatting Shortcut" nil
  ```

It doesn't work in all applications (prominent example: Microsoft Office), but it should work in all well-behaved Cocoa applications.

To find out what your application uses for *com.vendor.yourapp*, right-click the application bundle, select *Show Package Contents*, navigate to *Contents*, open *Info.plist* using a text editor, or better a property list editor like *Property List Editor* or *Xcode 4* (both part of Apple's developer tools) and look for *CFBundleIdentifier* or the like.

Comment: Tried both. The replacement shortcut showed up in the menu in the app. Rather, to speak concretely, the worthless formatting menu item = "\textsl - Slanted  [selection]" and now it is listed as having shortcut opt-shift-cmd-s. Similarly, shift-cmd-S is correctly listed as shortcut for "Save As." Furthermore, if there is no focus in a text editor, shift-cmd-S works for Save As. But if the focus is in the text editor, shift-cmd-S still does the dumb slanting shortcut instead of Save As.

Comment: I also tried the terminal trick, but got "Could not parse: \textsl - Slanted  [selection]. Try single-quoting it."; same message even when I tried single quoting or double backslashing. Could it be that I misidentified the bundle? The BundleIdentifier was just "texmaker"; I tried both com.texmaker and com.texmaker.texmaker in the terminal command. Thanks!

Comment: @Philip Since Texmaker is cross-platform, and neither looks nor behaves like a normal Mac OS X application, I am afraid it's not one of the *well-behaved Cocoa applications* whose menu item shortcuts can be changed. At all. It seems they hard-code things in a way that cannot be changed by Mac OS X methods... While I usually make sure my answers work, I don't *always* download and install all applications they refer to. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem; that makes sense, and you've been more than helpful and I have no expectation that you'd go to that trouble! So are you saying though, the typical methods to do this won't work? Or are you saying, based on how Texmaker was coded, that nothing will work? If the latter, I will accept your answer so the question can be closed. Thanks!

Comment: @Philip You need to contact the developers of TexMaker. I assume they primarily develop for other platforms, so they might not even be aware of this issue. The described method is how you usually do this for Mac OS X applications. Some, e.g. MS Office, are programmed in a way so this doesn't work, but they often provide their own menu customization methods. If they don't, you're pretty much out of luck. I doubt that the developers can somehow configure their GUI toolkit so this method works again. They'd need to provide their own methods of configuration. At least, all platforms would profit.

Comment: I think it might just be a common misconception that you can disable shortcuts by assigning them to nil. Property lists (even [old-style](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html) ones) don't seem to have anything like null values. The Keyboard preference pane shows shortcuts set to nil as L. If you try something like `defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add Minimize foo`, the shortcut will appear as disabled in most applications, but in some applications like Audacity it's shown as F.

Comment: @Lri Interesting. It does work though, so it might just be an undocumented implementation detail. So you're saying the only reliable solution is to assign a ridiculously difficult to press shortcut?

Comment: You could also assign them to something like U+200B (ZERO-WIDTH SPACE). That avoids the issue with applications like Audacity.