# mac iTerm2 unbind command + / Find Cursor shortkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, iterm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to remove a built-in shortcut from an application in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/287409/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-built-in-shortcut-from-an-application-in-mac-os-x)

I'm looking for some way to unbind **command + /** key by default binded to the View -> Find Cursor

I prefer to use it in different way in vim,  also it would be great to unbind much more iTerm2 key's during vim session.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to unbind the keyboard shortcuts when running vim only?

Comment: Please mention when you are running an unstable version. My stable 1.0.0 does not have that menu item.

Answer (score 8):

You can reassign keyboard shortcuts in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Applications*. Just select a different key combination there.

> [image]
>
> [image]

If you want to completely remove the keyboard shortcut from this menu item, [see this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/287419/22317).

Comment: To save some extra clicking, here's the solution (derived from the link) that worked for me: ``defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Find Cursor" nil`` (restart iTerm2 and the shortcut should be disabled). Use at your own risk :)