# Having disabled command-Q for Terminal via shell defaults command, how can I re-enable it?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell-script

I have a large, complex console program for execution via Terminal which solicits many responses from the user. Users may be habituated to use command-q to exit a program. This program has its own signal from the user to close down (the ESC key), which performs a "clean" shutdown - files finished and closed, log messages posted, etc. If the user responds positively to a prompt for quitting by command-Q, the shutdown is likely to be messy.

I could use the command suggested here - [How to disable command + q for Terminal on OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/222440/how-to-disable-command-q-for-terminal-on-osx) - (defaults write etc.) command to make it nil, but I need to obtain and restore its default value at the beginning and end of my program.

I used the defaults read command to try to determine the proper value for restoration, or to try to erase the nil, but various combinations of the identifiers (com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit Terminal") are all rejected.

Can anyone provide the proper parameters for restoration of the original status?
Thank you!

Comment: What was the exact command used initially, to remove Cmd/Q?

Comment: I found that command in "superuser.com/questions/222440/how-to-disable-command-q-for-terminal-on-osx" as:

"defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit Terminal" nil"

I am reluctant to mess with writing to defaults unless I'm sure not to do some irreparable damage. I'm clueless in there. Thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked question, the command to remove the Quit key command for Terminal is suggested as…

`defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit Terminal" nil`

This actually seems to work by accident. It actually changes the visible key command to N. It effectively disables Cmd/Q but is malformed. You can't clear a default key completely, you have to replace it with something else.
Try something no-one is ever going to hit by accident, like  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd> 
which would be
`defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Quit Terminal" @^~$Q`

You can remove this again with

`defaults delete com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents`

I can find no way to delete a single key by name, so this will clear all non-defaults added by a user.

The major downside of doing this is that Terminal - as with many apps - only reads this plist at launch [& then at quit may re-write it itself, based on actions taken during the session.]
Consequently, attempting to remove then return the key command whilst terminal is running will have no effect.

Comment: From https://discussions.apple.com/thread/428814
An example using "nil" instead of nil 
--
shell$ defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "View Source" "nil"
--
Perhaps that's the magic bullet. I will experiment, and report back.

Comment: No avail. After verifying that virginal Terminal launches without any NSUserKeyEquivalents, and writing the "nil", it posts in NSUserKeyEquivalents "Quit Terminal" as "nil" but Terminal's menu shows it as N and treats keystroke Cmd/N meaning to open a new window. Perhaps it can be assigned to ESC but then it's likely to intercept the program's ESC thus evading the clean shutdown.
What else could it be assigned to as equivalent to nil, I wonder. I could try an empty string "".

Comment: No. You cannot clear it entirely, you can only replace it with something else. I've added an example. It still won't work unless terminal is not running when you apply the shortcut change.

Comment: I tried it before your latest No... It reads from defaults as ' "" ' - two double quotes. So it records the expression for an empty string, but leaves the Cmd/Q intact.

Comment: So I wrote the default for Quit Terminal as "@&*" (three chars names beginning with 'a'). Reading defaults shows it like that. In Terminal it is shown as Cmd/& i.e. the four leaf clover key  and &, and that works as expected to quit Terminal.  Have I stumbled upon some obscure interpretational algorithm? Don't know if it will work on the next macOS release. It's difficult to keystroke. I will use it for now.

Comment: So I wrote the default for Quit Terminal as "@&*" (three chars names beginning with 'a'). Reading defaults shows it like that. In Terminal it is shown as Cmd/& i.e. the four leaf clover key  and &, and that works as expected to quit Terminal. 
 Have I stumbled upon some obscure interpretational algorithm? Don't know if it will work on the next macOS release.

Comment: A problem is that it endures quitting and relaunching Terminal, so I need to restore the normal Cmd/Q when my program closes down.
It's a bit difficult to keystroke. I will use it for now, test and report.

Comment: The *'obscure interpretational algorithm'* is already set out [albeit obliquely] in the answer. The characters `@^~$` act as cmd, ctrl, opt, shift. The next character is the non-mod key; the rest is ignored, as are any quotes. A string is implied, it doesn't need to be quoted.